# Is it possible to print a hollow box of using asterisks in Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python box class. The class has width and length attributes. I'd like to have a method that prints a a representation of the box given its width and length (which I have set to 5). When I use my print_box method I get something like this: <**console**.Box object at 0x109b73da0.

I've read about **str**, but I'm not sure it applies to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not printing a Box object I'm using the Box's attributes to govern how I print out asterisks.

Here's is my box class.

```
class Box():

    def __init__(self, width=5, length=5): 
        self.width = width
        self.height = length

    def print_box():
        for i in range(width):
           for j in range(length):
               if(i == 0 or i == width - 1 or j == 0 or j == length - 1):
                   print('*', end = '  ')
               else:
                   print(' ', end = '  ')

>>> mybox = Box()
>>> mybox.print_box
```

Then a hollow box would be printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not executing the function - you're just accessing it. Try `mybox.print_box()`.